# Hello World syntax error

Tags: go

When I try to compile the example from the front page of the go language website with the 6g compiler, I get this error:

`hello.go:5: syntax error near "<string>"`

I [search on Google reveals](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/300a24d431799ea5) that a few people have experienced this, but I have found no solution. The answer always seems to be: "It's works for me, you must do something wrong".

I've found a [description of the problem](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/9d515a056112c752/ef8d29b46f9bc384?lnk=gst&q=hello+world#ef8d29b46f9bc384) that dates back 5 months, so I suspect it's not a problem with the particular build of go that I'm using. Besides, I've tried pulling a newer version, and the problem persists.

The source code in question:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
 }
```

Btw, I'm saving the source code as UTF-8 with LFs for newlines. It shouldn't be a text encoding issue. I've also tried with different strings not containing "exotic" characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "which 6g".
You might be picking up an old build.
At least that was my case. I had an old 2009 build in my path.
After fixing the environment it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your special characters in there might cause conflicts with the compiler. Try to save this code in multiple ways using notepad (ANSI, UTF-8), and see whether the compiler will take any of them.

Comment: By specification, all Go source files must be UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Problems like this are typical when there's an encoding issue.

If you're on Windows, an editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can convert between many encoding formats, so I'd suggest converting your source to UTF-8 without BOM and then recompile.

If you're on Linux, there's a [guide available](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/determine-and-change-file-character-encoding.html) showing you how to determine and change a document's encoding.